# max-width on a div ignored on firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I realize there is already some question about that but I couldn't find an answer that suits my needs here.

here is a part of my css:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box; }

#outerWrapper{
max-width: 960px;
margin: 0px auto;
padding: 0px 18px;  
    }
```

inside of my outerWrapper div I have a percentage based grid.

No matter what I do in firefox my outerWrapper is about 1010px, 
in Chrome and safari it's working great.

I tried adding a fix width of 960px with a max-width of 960px but it didn't help.

Comment: Can you post a link to an example page?

Comment: It's really wired I can't re-create the problem on CodePen with firefox, and that problem doesn't happen don safari/chrome

Comment: Can you upload your page somewhere, or ideally provide a link to your page? It's pretty hard to debug with what you've provided.

Comment: Turns out that I had a zoom option activated on "localhost" tab it stayed even after rebooting the PC and updating firefox and wasn't showing anywhere. Hitting CTR+0 solved it. That was a stupid one...

Comment: It's Friday, sounds like it's home time!

Comment: @LorenzoPirondini You can answer your own question and then accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I had a zoom option activated on "localhost" tab it stayed even after rebooting the PC and updating firefox and wasn't showing anywhere. Hitting CTR+0 solved it. That was a stupid one...